# Issue Configuring my Shiny Server on a Virtual Machine with Bridged Adapter

Tags: r, linux, shiny, centos6, shiny-server

I am trying to deploy my Shiny App on a Virtual Machine (CentOS 6.7).  I have configured a bridged connection (I think I did it correctly) for the Virtual Machine, and I have my Static IP Address for the web application. The sample application works on `localhost:3838`.

I am behind a corporate proxy, so I am using a proxy to connect to the internet.  The proxy is set in `http_proxy`.  I can also connect to the internet successfully on the Virtual Machine.

When I try to access `<my_VM_static_IP_Address>:3838` the website does not connect.

I can ping both the `host` `IP address` and the `guest` `(static) IP address` successfully from another PC that is connected to the network.

```
    br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:F3:95:03:B5:CC  
          inet addr:<My Static IP Address>  Bcast:<my_broadcast_address>  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::72f3:95ff:fe03:b5cc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:69753 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9698 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:34003791 (32.4 MiB)  TX bytes:843817 (824.0 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:F3:95:03:B5:CC  
          inet6 addr: fe80::72f3:95ff:fe03:b5cc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:130187 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9704 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:45704171 (43.5 MiB)  TX bytes:845299 (825.4 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:814679 (795.5 KiB)  TX bytes:814679 (795.5 KiB)
```

My host default gateway and subnet mask are the same on the VM Guest and the host.

[image]

Any support is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Investigate whether a firewall on the host prevents port 3838 from being accessible from the rest of the network. It seems like you have a Windows host, correct?

Comment: Yep, I have a Windows host.  How can I check to see if the firewall on the host is preventing port 3838?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way to check is to telnet to that port on your guest OS's IP from another machine on the network. If the connection is refused with an error, you know something is blocking the port. A blank screen means an open port.

Answer (score 0):

From some other machine on the network, telnet to your guest VM's IP on port 3838. A blocked port will cause telnet to quickly return an error. If the telnet command sits with a blank screen, you have an open port.

Comment: I asked this question as a follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000510/trying-to-see-if-port-3838-is-open-not-sure-what-iptables-is-showing?noredirect=1#comment55756776_34000510